# Any reliable CDN available for SyntaxHighlighter?

Tags: javascript, cdn, syntaxhighlighter

Blow URL is the most common used for loading syntaxhighligter scripts into a page:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/

Currently, it redirects to the below location:

http://agorbatchev.typepad.com/pub/sh/VER_XXXX/scripts/

The approach seems naive and primitive for such popular script.
The problem is that it does not work for https requests.

Is there any proper CDN available for syntaxhighligter ?

I am looking for somewhere that provides a response for both HTTP and HTTPS without any redirect roundtrip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be available as an NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/syntaxhighlighter

This means you could take advantage of unpkg.com like so: https://unpkg.com/syntaxhighlighter@4.0.1

To load specific versions of the library, or a different JavaScript file, see the instructions on the unpkg homepage: https://unpkg.com/

This also of course means you can `npm install syntaxhighlighter` and use the package as an NPM module...